# Pending edits by users with under 2k reputation are not visible in the questions list

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, questions-page

I noticed that when I make an edit on sites where I have less than the 2k reputation required for the change to be immediate, that my edits are shown on the `/questions/######` View but on the `/questions` View. Is that by design or a bug?

**Edit Shows on `/questions/#####`**
[image: Image of a question view, contains the edit contents.]

**Edit Doesn't show on `/questions`**
[image: Image of the questions page, does not contain the edit contents.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost certainly by design; it shows it to you on the question along with the little info box so you're aware that it's still waiting for review, but checking every question in the question list to see if you happen to have a pending edit would take too long and not be particularly useful